# Added a scroll event listener to an element, but it moves the right way only when scrollTop !== 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I wrote this small script which has two lists - Finished/Active tasks, and you can either switch a task's list by hitting a button or read more about the task by hitting "more info". when hitting more info there's a new div element created, which I wanted to follow its hosts element Y position, and it halfway works.
So this is how it looks: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqR1z.png)

And here's the bug that im pretty sure happens when ever the scrollable-elements `scrollTop` isn't 0 (it is created the right way, and whenever I start scrolling it jumps right up and covers the task itself) :  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyYQv.png).

Here's the part of my code that's is incharge of identifying the amount of px scrolled, scroll direction and moving the "more info" div element, as well as the part that's incharge of creating it, I couldn't figure out where is the problem as I'm pretty new to coding overall and I'm not really familiar with css/html either.

```
createTooltip() {
    const tooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
    tooltipElement.className = 'card';
    const toolTipTemplate = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    const tooltipBody = document.importNode(toolTipTemplate.content, true);
    tooltipBody.querySelector('p').textContent = this.text;
    tooltipElement.append(tooltipBody);

    const hostElPosLeft = this.hostElement.offsetLeft;
    const hostElPostop = this.hostElement.offsetTop;
    const hostElHeight = this.hostElement.clientHeight;
    const parentElementScrolling = this.hostElement.parentElement.scrollTop;

    const x = hostElPosLeft + 20;
    const y = hostElPostop + hostElHeight - parentElementScrolling - 10;
    tooltipElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    tooltipElement.style.left = x + 'px';
    tooltipElement.style.top = y + 'px';

    const scrollHandler = () => {
      ulElement.addEventListener('scroll', yLogger);
    };
    tooltipElement.addEventListener('click', this.closeToolTip);
    tooltipElement.addEventListener('click', scrollHandler);
    this.element = tooltipElement;
    const ulElement = this.hostElement.parentElement;
    console.log(ulElement);

    let pxPosition = [0];
    let currentY = y;

    const yLogger = () => {
      let scrollDirection;
      let pxScrolled = 0;
      if (pxPosition.length <= 1) {
        pxPosition.push(ulElement.scrollTop);
      } else {
        pxPosition.push(ulElement.scrollTop);
        pxPosition.shift(ulElement);
      }
      console.log(pxPosition);
      if (pxPosition[1] < pxPosition[0]) {
        scrollDirection = 'up';
        pxScrolled = pxPosition[0] - pxPosition[1];
      } else if (pxPosition[0] < pxPosition[1]) {
        scrollDirection = 'down';
        pxScrolled = pxPosition[1] - pxPosition[0];
      }
      console.log(pxScrolled);
      console.log(scrollDirection);

      if (scrollDirection === 'down') {
        currentY = currentY - pxScrolled;
        console.log(currentY);
        tooltipElement.style.top = currentY + 'px';
      } else {
        scrollDirection === 'up';
        currentY = currentY + pxScrolled;
        console.log(currentY);
        tooltipElement.style.top = currentY + 'px';
      }
    };

    this.hostElement.closest('ul').addEventListener('scroll', yLogger);
  }
}
```

I'm adding the HTML and CSS snippets although I don't think they're neccesary since it was written by the course's instructor which im attending.

Here's the HTML snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Project Board</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/app.css" />
    <script src="assets/scripts/app.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <template id="tooltip">
      <h2>More Info</h2>
      <p></p>
    </template>
    <header id="main-header">
      <h1>Project Planner</h1>
    </header>
    <section id="active-projects">
      <header>
        <h2>Active Projects</h2>
      </header>
      <ul>
        <li
          id="p1"
          data-extra-info="Got lifetime access, but would be nice to finish it soon!"
          class="card"
          draggable="true"
        >
          <h2>Finish the Course</h2>
          <p>Finish the course within the next two weeks.</p>
          <button class="alt">More Info</button>
          <button>Finish</button>
        </li>
        <li
          id="p2"
          data-extra-info="Not really a business topic but still important."
          class="card"
          draggable="true"
        >
          <h2>Buy Groceries</h2>
          <p>Don't forget to pick up groceries today.</p>
          <button class="alt">More Info</button>
          <button>Finish</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <section id="finished-projects">
      <header>
        <h2>Finished Projects</h2>
      </header>
      <ul>
        <li
          id="p3"
          data-extra-info="Super important conference! Fictional but still!"
          class="card"
          draggable="true"
        >
          <h2>Book Hotel</h2>
          <p>
            Academind conference takes place in December, don't forget to book a
            hotel.
          </p>
          <button class="alt">More Info</button>
          <button>Activate</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <button id="im-done-btn">I'm Done!</button>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS snippet if relevant:

```html
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#main-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ff0062;
}

#main-header h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

section {
  margin: 1rem auto;
  width: 40rem;
  max-width: 90%;
}

section ul {
  padding: 1rem;
  max-height: 20rem;
  overflow: scroll;
}

section > h2 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  font: inherit;
  background: #ff0062;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ff0062;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.alt {
  background: white;
  color: #ff0062;
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button:hover,
button:active {
  background: #ff2579;
  border-color: #ff2579;
  color: white;
}

.card {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  padding: 1rem;
  background: white;
}

.droppable {
  background: #ffe0ec
}

#active-projects {
  border: 1px solid #870099;
}

#active-projects > header {
  background: #870099;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#active-projects header h2 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

#finished-projects {
  border: 1px solid #535353;
}

#finished-projects > header {
  background: #535353;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#finished-projects header h2 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML and CSS as well?

Comment: Yes I added both

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the Javascript you posted. It can not be used as it is now. I've found a similar example [here](https://codepen.io/Adhouma/pen/jOyvKRG). Is your code similar to this example?

Comment: Can you point out the problem?
It's a similar code but I modified it along the course in order to add my own features to it. I'm certain I have mistaken, but I would love to find out as to how and why.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved through CSS, and you can remove the following from your Javascript code:

```
tooltipElement.style.position = 'absolute';
tooltipElement.style.left = x + 'px';
tooltipElement.style.top = y + 'px';
```

Instead of that, change your CSS, by adding these:

```
li.card {
    position: relative;
}
div.card {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; /* or some other value, experiment until you find the one which works for you */
    left: 0; /* same as above */
    z-index: 1;
}
```

For this to work, the `div.card` element, which you are creating in your Javascript code, needs to be a child element of the appropriate `li.card` element. I'm also (perhaps erroneously) assuming that your original code is similar to [the one I found earlier](https://codepen.io/Adhouma/pen/jOyvKRG), and posted in the comment to your question, since I couldn't get your original code to run.

Your `position:absolute` wasn't working originally, because the position of the `li.card` parent was not explicitly set, which was defaulting it to `static`.

**EDIT** Forgot to mention the z-index bit. This is needed because your info box wouldn't be fully visible (it would be under the next `li.card` element).

Comment: First of all I'd like to thank you for your willingness to help.
Unfortanutely I don't really understand or know anything about css. I'll try fixing it similiarly to what you offered and I'll experiment with the values since it has they have to be variables instead of hardcoded. 
The course instructor is the one writing those so I didn't make any changes to them rather just changed the script. 
Do you think deep knowledge in css is needed in order to be a good js developer?

Comment: You don't need to have a deep knowledge of CSS, but knowing and understanding the basics is necessary for anything related to the web.

Comment: Well I started learning JS mostly to understand the language and move ahead to solidity.
I don't know how fond you are with Solidity, but based on your knowledge and exprience would you recommend going through basic css learning in order to improve my ability or do you think it is not needed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Solidity, but from what I've just read about it, it doesn't appear like you need to know CSS to be able to do your stuff in Solidity.